# AVD запускается, но видно только половину экрана

Tags: avd, android-studio, debian

Исходные данные:
 1. ОС Linux 3.2.0-4-amd64 Debian 3.2.63-2+deb7u2
 2. Android Studio 1.0.1

Пробовал разные виртуальные устройства. Разные System images. Результат тот же. В текущем варианте работает намного быстрее, чем Image с архитектурой x86, но показывает только половину экрана. Несмотря на это, можно потыкать мышкой в "невидимую" часть экрана и получить результат (если попасть в кнопку, например). Кто-то сталкивался с таким? Как лечится?

Answer (score 1):

Лично я перестал пользоваться стандартными avd после того как узнал о Genymotion.

Скачать тут https://www.genymotion.com/#!/download

Описание и установка https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BgAgNBI498Y